# int datatype overflow in a for loop (in python)

Tags: python, for-loop, overflow

This is my python script that gives me an exception like this

```
IndexError: index out of range: 202252
```

if I put the 900000 to something smaller it works great. The function `randint` works with a lot of bigger numbers and that is not the place where the exception is thrown the exception is thrown at `for q in range(long(fromline),long(fromline)+500L):` this line, I think I has some problems with the long int conversions or some kind of data-type overflow.

```
fromline = random.randint(1,900000)
for q in range(long(fromline),long(fromline)+500L):
   if (len(str(lines[fromline+q])) < 3:
      print "blabla"
```

**EDIT**

```
#read the lines from file
f = open("asd.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

# print "if I uncoment this, then exception is thrown" +str(len(lines))
```

if I do this

print lines[1]
print lines[100000]
...

it works just fine, I am really confused about this , I have never seen similar problem like this

**EDIT**

I find what exactly is my problem, please see my answer

Comment: What? You're getting an `IndexError`, that has nothing to do with integer overflows.  How many `lines` do you have?

Comment: I know it looks strange, but if I put in comment "for q in range(long(fromline),long(fromline)+500L):
   if (len(str(lines[fromline+q])) < 3:
      print "blabla"" this part then the script it is working great... I have very big strings something with more then 1000000 characters...

Comment: @Lukap A string may have millions of characters, but `lines` must have enough elements to access the 202252nd index!

Comment: Well your file clearly does not contain at least 202252 lines.  You've read the the contents of the file into the list, `lines`.  You ran that code and it gave you an `IndexError` saying the index `202252` is out of range... you commented out the block of code that includes the `lines[fromline+q]` line and it worked... `10000` is clearly less than `202252`.  How are you not seeing what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my problem !

well thanks for all of you for the help, I tried this in pure python script and it is working fine. But the problem is that the spinet I show to you is just a part of one very big script that runs on phones. YES the python part is okey, I was searching the problem in python script but it is not there. The problem is in the limitations of the phone, namelly the 65536 lines is the limitation of few variables that I am using.For example when more then 65536 lines is put in the lines variable then the IndexError is thrown.

I hope this will help to someone who uses monkeyrunner with python.

As a summary when you write a python script that runs on phone (for example with monkeyrunner) always have in mind that some things will not work as you expected and some scripts that works fine on pc will NOT work when you run them on phone

Comment: Might have been nice to know you were running it on a phone.  :-)  But glad to know you found it ... and to hear about monkeyrunner, that looks like fun.

Comment: well it is fun on the older phones with version 1.6 or so. On the latest phones like Samsung S2 everything works fine. Do not be scared to write something for mobile devices , but if you have an requirement for devices with sdk version 1.6 you should definitely think twice :-)

Answer (score 3):

There's no integer overflow in python. Maybe your list is not large enough to access at index 202252. Check the length of `lines`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be safer - though perhaps not as officiant - to use:

```
for line in lines[long(fromline):long(fromline)+500L]:
   if len(str(line)) < 3:
      print "blabla"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 32 bit system the maximum number of elements in an array is 536,870,912 and the max int is 2147483647 which as you can see is much bigger  than the 202252 in your example. Also, even if you would do like:

```
 >>> int(10000000000000000000)
 10000000000000000000L
```

So like the other said there is no integer overflow. And the exception is quite explicit, it's a indexerror so your list is not big enough. To be on the safe side, and if you don't know how big your lines array is, I would rewrite the code like this:

```
max_index = len(lines) - 1
fromline = random.randint(1, max_index/2 - 500)
for q in range(long(fromline),long(fromline)+500L):
   if (len(str(lines[fromline+q])) < 3:
      print "blabla"
```

-------------- After your edit --------------------

Your edit example makes no sense in the indexerror. The index which is not present is 202252 so of course lines[1] and lines[10000] should work. Just do the same and print len(lines) and see if it's smaller than 202252.

Comment: yes you are right there is no int overflow on pc !, but there is definitely an overflow when you do execute the script on HTC Hero with monekyrunner, that is my problem !, the logic in the script is good and it works in every scenario but only on pc :(, when I run it on devices is completely new story. But thanks for killing the doubt that the problem is in the pythons int

Answer (score 0):

Why in the world wouldn't you just slice that list and iterate over the slice?

```
for q in lines[fromline:fromline+501]:
   if len(q) < 3:
      print "blabla"
```

I took out a bunch of unnecessary type conversions as well (assuming that all your lines are in fact already strings). Note that Python will convert things to longs for you when they get too big to be integers, so you will rarely need to convert numbers to long yourself.

The bug in your original code, by the way, is that you are picking a random line, and that random line is within 500 lines of the last line, and when you try to iterate past the end of the list, you get an `IndexError`.

Comment: I try to isolate the sniped and I past it here just small  fraction of the code... the problem in the IndexError is not in the logic of the program, all of the scenarios are carefully handled, the problem was with the limitations of the phone :(, but thanks for you answer it helped me to realize that I do not have problems with int overflow, unfortunately this is true only on pc but not when this is run on HTC Hero, but tnx for clarifying those things to me